# Rxjava creates a loop when retrieving then updating an item from database

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a challenge with rxjava, there's an observable to retrieve an item from database. I subscribe to this observable and on successful retrieval of an item from database i update that item. Problem is immediately after updating the item, my observable to get an item starts emitting and the update method is called again hence creating a loop.

Sample code

```
mOrderRepository.getOrder(orderId)
 .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
 .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui())
 .subscribe((Order order) -> {
 // i calculate amount due after payment then update this order
    order.setAmountDue(amountDue);
    mOrderRepository.updateOrder(order);
});
```

Comment: Well why *does* fetching data trigger writes?

Comment: It is writing the data (i.e updating that item) that triggers the fetching of data again.

Comment: If it is supposed to be one item, use `take(1)` just after `getOne()`.

Comment: @akarnokd i will add that, but i will still face that problem because after getting that item then updating it, the getOne observable is triggered again then i get that same item update it, getOne observable is triggered. I hope you now see my issue

Comment: If you want to update the entry why not do in directly? So orderRepo.updateOne(id). If you try to update entry after fetch or any other operation try to aply your changes to the object before writing it to db (but do not mutate it in rx stream).

Comment: I'm quite sure the logic you intend to achieve with your unspecified Rx chain is incorrect, and that's why you are running into this problem

Comment: How do you know you'll still face that problem? @EpicPandaForce the OP is a typical case of an infinite datasource many Android databases do by default. Updating a record by any means will trigger an ongoing query, so you have to either stop the flow before that, filter out already seen items or try using Single to ensure a single value response (if the db API supports it).

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I have editted the code in my question, have a look then kindly tell me where the logic is wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

If `getOrder(orderId)` returns a `Flowable<Order>`, that will receive Order again and again on each update, then this should be executed within the context of a separate `Single` that can be used to update the item for the given `orderId`.

```
public static final Object UNIT = new Object(); // avoid emitting `null`

public void updateOrder(final long orderId, final long amountDue) {
    Single.fromCallable(() -> UNIT)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap((ignored) -> getOrder(orderId).firstOrError()) // <-- convert Flowable to Single
            .doOnSuccess(order -> {
                order.setAmountDue(amountDue);
                mOrderRepository.updateOrder(order);
            }).subscribe();
}
```

Or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an `Order` object every time it is updated in the database, and every time you get that `Order` object you update it in the database, it will loop indefinitely. The missing logic should answer the following question: When should the object NOT be updated?

One solution, as @akarnokd suggested, is to limit the retrieval to the first emitted item by specifying take(1):

```
mOrderRepository.getOrder(orderId)
 .take(1)
 .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
 .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui())
 .subscribe((Order order) -> {
    order.setAmountDue(amountDue);
    mOrderRepository.updateOrder(order);
});
```

However, this may not be the logic you desire in the scenario where the order could legitimately be updated several times from another source. In this case, it may make sense to compare whether the received order's `amountDue` (or whatever other properties are relevant) is different than the updated amount. If so, update the order.

```
mOrderRepository.getOrder(orderId)
 .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
 .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui())
 .subscribe((Order order) -> {
    // assuming `amountDue` has already been defined
    if (!order.getAmoundDue().equals(amountDue)) {
      order.setAmountDue(amountDue);
      mOrderRepository.updateOrder(order);
    }
});
```